# Windows Mobile 7 MAP Control ZoomBarVisibility

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
   <map:Map Name="MapControl" CredentialsProvider="xxx" ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed"></map:Map>
```

Sill displays + - zoom buttons, how can I disable them?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me :-

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <map:Map Name="MapControl"
                 ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed"
                 CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed"
                 LogoVisibility="Collapsed"></map:Map>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: tried that, still displays, maybe its when I add pins to the control?